# How can I secure raw sql CDbCriteria condition (anti sql injection) in Yii 1.1?

Tags: php, sql, yii, yii1.x

I'm dealing with an Yii 1.1 app.

Part of the search method use `CDbCriteria` and raw sql.

I was wondering how can I still use the raw sql code and make it more secure from sql injections?

Here is a code example:

```
if (!empty($this->textToSearch)) {
    $text_condition = <<<EOC
(
    topic LIKE "%{$this->textToSearch}%" OR
    main LIKE "%{$this->textToSearch}%" OR  
)
EOC;
    $criteria->addCondition($text_condition);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use params to pass untrusted data to query. Note that `%`, `_` and `\` chars has special meaning in SQL query, so you need to escape it too.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
if (!empty($this->textToSearch)) {
    $text_condition = <<<EOC
(
    topic LIKE :text_to_search OR
    main LIKE :text_to_search  
)
EOC;
    $criteria->addCondition($text_condition);
    $textToSearch = strtr($this->textToSearch, [
        '%' => '\%',
        '_' => '\_',
        '\\' => '\\\\',
    ]);
    $criteria->params[':text_to_search'] = "%{$textToSearch}%";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there more caharcetrs i could escape? and what about escaping values with 'Yii::app()->db->quoteValue($string)'? can 'quoteValue ' join your solution for anti sql injection pattern?

Comment: No need to escape more characters. Escaping `%` is not related to SQLi, it just prevent from treating `%` as "anything" instead of `%`. Params are enough for SQLi protection. `quoteValue()` could be replacement for using params, but you should prefer params anyway.

Comment: thanks again! so if i understand correctly i should use strtr to escape characters only if i use the parameter  in a 'like' contextl? e.g: do i need to escape charecters in this kind of sql statments "blabla.timestamp < :usertimestamp"?

Comment: Yes, it is only relevant for `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` conditions. You can take a look at `CDbCriteria` source: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1a5d93dda88c1f3e8cc73ceb2b265c818612d8dd/framework/db/schema/CDbCriteria.php#L251-L260